# Match Production Licenses option not shown under Company Information in Sandbox

Tags: sandbox, licenses

I want to match the user licenses in Sandbox with Production. I was referring to this link [Match Production Licenses](http://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/summer14/release-notes/rn_forcecom_sandbox_copy_licenses.htm). But I could not find the option for Match Production Licenses under Company Information.

**Sandbox Details**

Organization Edition: Enterprise Edition.

Salesforce Release: Discover Winter '17.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [link](http://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/summer14/release-notes/rn_forcecom_sandbox_copy_licenses.htm) you provided includes the reason that a sandbox on Winter 17 will not be able to match licences with Production orgs that are still on Summer 16 release. You will have to wait till the two are back on the same release.

> Matching production licenses requires that your sandbox and production are on the same Salesforce release. If your sandbox has already been upgraded to the next release—for example, during sandbox preview—but production hasn't been upgraded yet, you can't match production licenses in sandbox.

Production Orgs will be moved over in October 2016 to Winter 17 release - see this for the [current schedule](http://www.slideshare.net/RoyGilad/salesforce-winter-17-release-milestones) . Remember the actual dates may move slightly and vary by which node you are on.

The match licences button when it is available appears on the company information page as below.

[image]

Comment: Okay. So once Production gets upgraded with the Sandbox release this option will be available. Is this a button like "Buy More Licenses" and it would be shown to me (System Admin)?

Comment: That is correct. Unfortunately I can't grab a screen shot as the sandboxes I have available are all onto Winter 17 now.